# Onchange function with options to change textbox string not working

Tags: javascript, html

**Goal: Show a string that changes entered text from textbox based on a selected option.
Problem: I am a beginner - unsure why the code is not functioning. See below.**

```
<main class="color-design">
<form id="formSentence"
 <p>`enter code here`
   <label for="txtSentence">Enter a sentence</label>
   <input type="text" id="txtSentence">
 </p>

 <p>
  <select id="selSentenceChange" change="sentenceChange()">
   <option value="choose">Choose One</option>
   <option value="upperCase">Print in upper case</option>
   <option value="replacement">Replace first "e" with "X"</option>
   <option value="firstLetter">Print the first letter in the string</option>
  </select>
 </p>
</form>
<div id="results"</div>
<!-- end of results div -->
</main>

<script>
  function sentenceChange ()
  {

    var change = document.getElementById("selSentenceChange").value;
    var sentence = "txtSentence";

    if (change == "upper")
    {
    sentence = txtSentence.toUpperCase();
    }
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = sentence;
  }
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting?   on first glance, txtSentence isn't defined

Comment: It's `onchange` in this element `<select id="selSentenceChange" onchange="sentenceChange()">`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issue on your HTML and JS. I will add them below to highlight.

1. Select `change` need to be call like this `onchange`
2. You are NOT getting the value of your `input` you need to either use `getElementById('txtSentence')` or `querySelector('#txtSentence')`
3. Also you not matching your option `value` which is `uppercase` NOT `upper`
4. Also it's not ideal to use `.innerHTML` as its not recemended use `.textContent` which i have used as well to display results select option

All the `options` are working as expected.

1. The first option will convert word to `toUpperCase` using [toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)
2. Second option will replace first `e` from entered words with `X` using [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
3. Third option will get the first letter from the entered strings using [chatAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

This will store the results and display in the `results` div

```
var results
```

Demo: Run snippet to below see it working.

```js
function sentenceChange() {

  var change = document.getElementById("selSentenceChange").value;
  var sentence = document.getElementById("txtSentence").value;
  var results;
  if (change === "upperCase") {
    results = sentence.toUpperCase();
  } else if (change === "replacement") {
    results = sentence.replace('e', 'X')
  } else if (change === "firstLetter") {
    results = sentence.charAt(0)
  }
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results;
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main class="color-design">
  <form id="formSentence">
    <p>
      <label for="txtSentence">Enter a sentence</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtSentence">
    </p>

    <p>
      <select id="selSentenceChange" onchange="sentenceChange()">
        <option value="choose">Choose One</option>
        <option value="upperCase">Print in upper case</option>
        <option value="replacement">Replace first "e" with "X"</option>
        <option value="firstLetter">Print the first letter in the string</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </form>
  <div id="results"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @user13939918 You are welcome. Glad that i helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selSentenceChange");

select.addEventListener("change", sentenceChange);

function sentenceChange(e) {
  var change = e.target.value;

  var sentence = document.getElementById("txtSentence").value;

  if (change == "upperCase") {
    sentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
  }
  document.getElementById("results").innerText = sentence;
}
```

```html
<main class="color-design">
  <form id="formSentence"><p>
    <label for="txtSentence">Enter a sentence</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtSentence"/>
    </p>

    <p>
      <select id="selSentenceChange">
        <option value="choose">Choose One</option>
        <option value="upperCase">Print in upper case</option>
        <option value="replacement">Replace first "e" with "X"</option>
        <option value="firstLetter">Print the first letter in the string</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </form>
  <div id="results"> </div>
    <!-- end of results div -->
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked as well. I haven't gone over DOM Events and this was extremely useful.